# Symfony change app locale not showing right links at homePage

Tags: php, symfony

am trying to translate a project to English, i've changed all routes annotation to multiple language style:

I am using symfony 4.2

```js
/**
     * @Route({
     *     "nl": "/",
     *     "en": "/en"
     * })
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
```

This is the link en my example:

```js
<a class="customerservice" href="{{ path('web_page') }}">
  <i class="fal fa-headset" aria-hidden="true"></i> Klantenservice
</a>
```

This is the controller where the link goes:

```js
 /**
     * @Route({
     *     "nl": "/klantenservice{slug}",
     *     "en": "/en/customer-service{slug}"
     * }, name="web_page", requirements={"slug": ".+"})
     */
    public function pageAction($slug = '/')
    {
        /** @var WebPageRepository $repository */
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(WebPage::class);

        if (!$webPage = $repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $slug])) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("web_page");
        }

        return $this->render('@FrontOffice/WebPage/page.html.twig', [
            'page' => $webPage,
            'pages' => $repository->getAllForMenu()
        ]);
    }
```

And i share my localeListner in case it needed:

```js
<?php

namespace FrontOfficeBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) return;

        if ( $locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);

            return;
        }

        $lang = explode('.', $request->getHost());
        if (!isset($lang[2]) || !$lang[2]) return;
        $request->setLocale($lang[2] == 'be' ? 'nl_BE' : $lang[2]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

Parameter.yaml:

```js
parameters:
  locale: nl
  default_date_format: "eee dd-MM-y HH:mm"
  product_upload_directory: "%var_path%/upload/"

services:
  _defaults:
    public: true
    autowire: true
    bind:
      $buckarooTestMode:    '%buckaroo_test_mode%'
      $buckarooCertificate: '%buckaroo_certificate%'
      $buckarooWebsiteKey:  '%buckaroo_website_key%'
```

routes.yaml:

```js
set_session:
  path: '/_session'
  defaults: { _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\SessionController::setSessionAction }

plein_search_categories:
  path:     /zoeken/categorieen/{searchTerm}
  defaults: { _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\CategorySearchController::indexAction, searchTerm: null }

plein_search:
  path:     /zoeken/{searchTerm}
  defaults: { _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\SearchController::indexAction, searchTerm: null }

plein_search_index:
  path:     /zoeken/
  defaults: { _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\SearchController::indexAction, searchTerm: null }

plein_catalog_autocomplete:
  path:     /catalog/autocomplete
  defaults: { _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\AutocompleteController::indexAction }

homepage:
  path:
    nl: /
    en: /en
  controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction

backOfficeRouting:
  resource: "@BackOfficeBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /intranet
  condition: "%intranet% === 1"

esbClientRouting:
  resource: "@PleinEsbClientBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation

fos_js_routing:
  resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing-sf4.xml"

core_routing:
  resource: "@PleinCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /

plein_brand:
  defaults:
    _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\BrandController::indexAction
  path: '/merken/'

plein_brand_router:
  defaults:
    _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\BrandController::brandAction
  path: '/merken/{slug}/'

plein_review_router:
  defaults:
    _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\ReviewController::writeAction
  path: '/review/schrijven/{product}/'

plein_review_list:
  defaults:
    _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\ReviewController::listAction
  path: '/reviews/{product}/'

plein_promotion_router:
  defaults:
    _controller: FrontOfficeBundle\Controller\CategoryController::promotionsAction
  path: '/aanbiedingen/'

themesRouting:
  resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation

_liip_imagine:
  resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"

frontOfficeRouting:
  resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation
```

Everything works ok in all pages except homePage, for example when i'am at profile (English locale):

http://domain-name.com/en/profile

[image]

when i hover this link it shows: http://domain-name.com/en/customer-service

But!!! when i am at home page (English locale):

http://domain-name.com/en

when i hover the same link it shows: http://domain-name.com/klantservice

so the same locale at two diffrent pages but in all other pages except home the application shows all links with the correct locale. At home page it shows the default always. any tip pls?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved to build the links and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I just did sharing some extra info, i hope it is enough @NicoHaase

Comment: I think after looking to my Profiler that i have request and sub request, main request is with the good locale and the sub request is with default, this caused by forward the page instead of render. so can you help?

Comment: u might want to parametrize route annotation and use `href="{{ path('web_page', {_locale: app.request.locale }) }}"` the session stored locale to generate links